# Creating a new class in R dataframe

Tags: r

I am in need of creating a new class in R dataframe. Example,

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("A", "B"), b = c("D","S"))
class(asd$b) <- "New"
```

As you see, I have a created a new class "New". But when I do below operation, I do not get a

```
asd %>% select_if(is.New) 
Error in is_logical(.predicate) : object 'is.New' not found
```

Expected output

```
   b
1  D
2  S
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because you create a class of "New" doesn't mean a function with the name `is.New` was also created. The generic form of `is()` takes a class name as a character value. You would use it like

```
asd %>% select_if(~is(., "New"))
```

And if you wanted to create `is.New` you could do

```
is.New <- function(x) is(x, "New")

asd %>% select_if(is.New)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `select` with `where`

```
library(dplyr)
asd %>%
    select(where(~ is(., "New")))
```

-output

```
 b
1 D
2 S
```